# can't install SDV in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, sdv

I am trying to install SDV package using `pip install sdv` , but without success.

final part of the error log :

```
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> scipy

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for output from the failure.
```

I tried installing scipy seperatly with pip, same issue.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the [*full text* of any errors or tracebacks](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/359146).

Comment: The error logs can be long, but as mentioned in the hint ("hint: See above for output from the failure."), you need to check previous parts of the log for more google-able error messages.

Answer (score 1):

The current release `SDV 0.17.0` does not support `python 3.10`. If you are using a `python 3.10` version, downgrade your working environment to `python 3.9`.

Currently `sdv 0.17.0` supports `python 3.6 3.7 3.8 and 3.9`.